# clear all variables in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

can any body tell me what command is used to clear all variables in rails console?

e.g.

```
1.9.1 :001 > permissions = {:show => true}
 => {:show=>true} 
1.9.1 :001 > foo = "bar"
 => "bar"
```

I need a command that can get all variables reset to nil without a restart of rails console itself.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @cih reload! doesn't reset variables in my case though

Comment: @Sarun, check if my sol is working, its not 100% precise answer. But  its a workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
local_variables.each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") }
```

`local_variables` returns the list of symbols of all local variables in the current scope

```
a, b = 5, 10
local_variables # => [:b, :a]
```

Using `each` you can iterate over this list an use `eval` to assign their values to `nil`.

You can also do the same thing with `instance_variables` and  `global_variables`. For example

```
(local_variables + instance_variables).each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") }
```

---

By the way, if you are going to use it more than once, it might be helpful to define such method in `~/.irbrc` file to make it accessible for all irb sessions (didn't test it in rails console).

```
class Binding
  def clear
    eval %q{ local_variables.each { |e| eval("#{e} = nil") } }
  end
end
```

Then, inside `irb` session

```
a = 5
binding.clear
a # => nil
```

Comment: what if he made any instance variables, this is not a command dude!

Comment: I was looking for how to show all the variables I declared in the console, this helped me.

Answer (score -3):

Do one thing, type

```
irb 'another'
```

and then press ctrl+l

now check the values of your variables.
It works.

Comment: It doesn't reset variables to `nil`, it changes the scope of irb to the string object 'another'. For example, if you type `self` after `irb 'another'`, you will get `"another\n"`.

Comment: Yeah, friend -  it changes the scope, and creates a new session; if u check local variables from earlier session, it will report 'undefined variable' and value of instance variables will be nil. I do not think there is a single command in which you reset the whole session in one shot. Like reload! in rails console.

Comment: Well, maybe it's worth to mention that all rails console's helpers like `app`, `controller`, `reload!` will disappear as well.